# How could I read all boolean values from NSUserDefaults into a dictionary using swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Lets say I have my defaults NSUserDefaults object like

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "UseTouchID")
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "SetAutoSaveIsOn")
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "DoSomethingIfActive")
defaults.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "LastRun")
```

How could I read all boolean values from NSUserDefaults into a dictionary using swift? Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

For example for one bool value:

```
defaults.boolForKey("UseTouchID")
```

If you want reach all bool value at once, you can create a dictionary, append bool values after all that you can use this code block,

`defaults.setObject(yourBoolDictionary, forKey:"BoolDictionary")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read multiple items from `NSUserDefaults` at once filtered by type.

But you can read the entire key/value pairs with

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()
```

but this includes also all global keys and values (the output of `defaults read -g` in Terminal.app)